# Haskell types/type conversion (sqrt,floor)

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement the Cantor Pairing using Haskell. The encoding of a list of ints is working fine, the decoding however is just not working due to type errors.

I tried nearly everything I could think of, but nothing would work out:

```
cantorDecode :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
cantorDecode e zs
    | length zs == 0    = cantorDecode y [x,y]
    | head zs == 0      = map toInteger $ tail zs    
    | otherwise         = cantorDecode y ((head zs)-1 : (tail zs) ++ [x,y])
        where
            a = fromRational e
            w = floor ((s-1.0)/2.0)
            s = fromIntegral $ sqrt(8.0*e+1.0) :: Double
            t = fromRational $ (w^2+w)/2.0
            y = toInteger $ e - (toInteger $ floor t)
            x = toInteger $ (toInteger w) - (toInteger y)
```

1. input is the next Integer to decode
2. input is the list with the already decoded Integers

As you can see, I'm using `sqrt`, `floor` and other things, so it's a bit messy...

Comment: You should also add the error you encounter.

Comment: I think your problem is here: `8.0*e+1.0` if I see it right `e` is an Integer so you cannot use it here - it should be ok like this: `8.0 * fromIntegral e * 1.0`

Comment: next problem same line - `fromIntegral` and whatever arises from `sqrt` ... try `sqrt . fromIntegral $ 8*e+1` instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK that does look desperate. A couple points:

1. You certainly don't want `fromRational`, since you have no actual `Rational`s here. Also, `fromRational` and `toFractional` are both strictly less general than their combination `realToFrac`, although you don't need that either - these are all for converting between *different* floating point/rational types, but you have only one involved, `Double`.
2. You don't want `toInteger`, which is only for converting between different `Integral` types. You *do* want its generalization `fromIntegral` which converts from an `Integral` type to a general `Num`.

You should make a clear decision exactly which of your variables are `Integer`s, and which are `Double`s. Then use `fromIntegral` to convert from `Integer` to `Double`, and `floor` or another similar function to convert from `Double` to `Integer`, when necessary. You have several attempts there to convert between the *same* type (basically, all your `toInteger`s.)

Given this, you can clean your type-conversion code up into (adding explicit type annotations for clarity):

```
cantorDecode :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
cantorDecode e zs
    | length zs == 0    = cantorDecode y [x,y]
    | head zs == 0      = tail zs    
    | otherwise         = cantorDecode y ((head zs)-1 : (tail zs) ++ [x,y])
        where
            w = floor ((s-1.0)/2.0)             :: Integer
            w' = fromIntegral w                 :: Double
            s = sqrt(8.0*fromIntegral e+1.0)    :: Double
            t = (w'^2+w')/2.0                   :: Double
            y = e - floor t                     :: Integer
            x = w - y                           :: Integer
```

Comment: you should change `w'^2` into `w'^(2::Integer)` to remove the last warning IMO

Comment: @CarstenKönig I disagree, that means essentially outlawing plain mathematical notation because of a silly Haskell defaulting issue of no real consequence.

Comment: it's your answer - I just like my code do not have warnings - that'S why I added IMO

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen: Thank you very much for putting so much effort into explaining this to me! I had a totally wrong understanding of those types and type conversions, but thanks to your explanation I've gotten a good insight into it. Thanks again!